# Three monitor set up - how to set one monitor to grayscale?

Tags: display, macos, thunderbolt-display

I have a Retina MacBook Pro (mid-2015), powering an Apple Cinema Display 24" monitor, and a run-of-the-mill, cheap and poor quality/old Samsung monitor. I've connected both of these displays to the RMBP via Thunderbolt.

Now, since the Samsung monitor is old, I would prefer to use it in grayscale. I'm trying to figure out how to use macOS Sierra to change that, and that monitor only, to grayscale. I would only use it to display information that can be viewed in grayscale (Slack chats, email, Terminal, logs, Mixpanel/Geckoboard analytics, you know, not browse websites). I am well aware that the Accessibility -settings in System Preferences can be applied so that each of the three screens is grayscale. I'm not looking for that. If I was looking for that, I'd just launch a Grayswitcha-app I made with AppleScript.

I'm looking to set the Samsung, and only the Samsung, to grayscale.

Is there some way of doing this?

Would really appreciate any assistance on this.

PS Not looking for "change all your apps to be grayscale, and then if you want the same app to be colored too on a different display, do another profile/alias for each and every one of the apps, then run it with the color... oh hang on that's a great deal of work, do it anyway cos this is a good solution" -type solutions :(
PPS also not looking for "solutions" where i'm told to properly color profile correct the Samsung, If I was, I'd have solved that already by asking a different way. I'm looking to shoot grayscale data at the Samsung and that is really all.

Comment: @Allan Yeah, I originally read it as 'proxy' too, but it's _poxy_, as in something that's worthless. I assume the OP is thinking it will work better if it's being used a monochromatic screen rather than a colour screen.

Comment: @Monomeeth - I see what you're saying, but I didn't get any of that from the post. Proxy is "substitute for" or "act on another's behalf" (i.e. proxy server) and he didn't say *why* he *thought* there would be a benefit to it being mono.

Comment: @Allan Yeah, the context behind the question is rather vague. In fact, looking at it again, it reads to me like it could be an XY problem.

Comment: Greyscale setting is available in the Accessibility Settings page, however it will affect all monitors not just one.

Comment: I wonder if you could accomplish this by setting really weird values in "Calibrate Color"...

Comment: If you're just using your Samsung monitor for Terminal or console logs, why would you want to set it to mono when 1) Terminal is 8-bit color with predominantly white foreground and black background  already and 2) Setting it to mono removes the ability to see the colored output (i.e. directories, read-only files, etc) that terminal is capable of display?  Color accuracy isn't critical here, but color is beneficial.

Comment: @Allan I wrote poxy, and did not mean proxy, instead poxy. I was just trying to be glib, to drive home how poor the screen was, being unable to display even differences between pale blue and paler blue (like on Facebook). poxy=wack. I've since then edited the post so there's no answers based on misreading poxy as proxy. at Monomeeth: yep, poxy as in worthless. Not proxy. Again, edited the post. I'm not running Proxy servers or Proxy monitors, I wouldn't know what they are. I have both devices connected via Thunderbolt.

Comment: @Allan It's not Terminal only. I might at times use Slack - on any of the three different displays  - I can't very well set Slack to be grayscale when it's on the Samsung monitor, and full color when it's on the CinemaDisplay or on the laptop screen. I don't want to change the settings of apps (10+), or create different aliases "slack-color" vs. "slack-grayscale", I run Firefox, Chromium, Chrome, Slack, Mail, Terminal, MixPanel / Geckoboard etc etc etc, I can't be having multiple commandline startups for all those, I just need one monitor to be grayscale, that's all.

Comment: @Allan I've edited the post again, to make it more accurate - might be running any number of apps on the Samsung display - can't start doing grayscale profiles for apps - then once I disconnect the screens, I'm stuck with grayscale apps on a retina display, not a solution, unfortunately. I understand your sentiment, however, I get it, but if I really was going to only show grayscale terminal screens then maybe that'd work but I'd still be stuck with grayscale terminal screens after disconnecting.. I'm not looking to increase fiddling, but to simplify. I hope that's ok with you :)

Comment: *"to drive home how poor the screen was, being unable to display even differences between pale blue and paler blue"*  -- time to **throw it out**.  Take it to your nearest electronics recycling center and pick up a "new" cheap one on [craigslist](https://miami.craigslist.org/brw/sys/6163034279.html) or [ebay](http://ebay.to/2sopnPH)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest two options:

Firstly, check the controls of the monitor itself (usually in some terrible UI with only two buttons) to see if you can de-color the screen somehow.

The second is to create custom display profile that would turn the monitor to greyscale. You can't actually select a greyscale profile as the monitor's profile, so you would need to create an RGB version. You could do this in the display calibrator wizard.

Comment: thanks, what's a display calibrator wizard? is that macOS native?

Comment: @esaruoho In the drop-down list to select a profile (System PRefs > Displays), it says "Customize" at the bottom. Then you can define your own profile.

Answer (score -1):

The solution isn't to use grayscale! The solution is to create correct color profiles for monitors, so that they give correct colors. Just use a display calibrator, and calibrate the profile of both monitors (internal and external), so that the colors show up almost the same in both. (I use an i1 display pro profiler. You can borrow one, or buy a used one, or buy and return if if you do not like it.)

Comment: The OP said "I'm looking to set the Samsung, and only the Samsung, to grayscale." - OP didn't seem to needing to samsung's display to be showing correct color, rather, wanting it to be grayscaled.

Comment: agreed, this isn't a solution to the problem i'm looking to solve. i don't need "correct color profiles", i just need a specific monitor to be grayscale. so unless your correct color profile gives me grayscale, you're not getting to the gist of the problem at all.

Comment: The OP said "since the **color accuracy** is pretty weak on the Samsung monitor - I'm trying to figure out how to use macOS Sierra to change that, and that monitor only, to grayscale". Using a color calibrator would eliminate the very first problem (color accuracy), which avoids the need to make that monitor gray scale in the first place (at least if the OP meant what they said). If, on the other hand, the OP did not mean what they said, then we cannot guess. The OP should explain why they really need grayscale, or why they are unwilling to try a calibrator that solves their accuracy issue.

Comment: @HarryM hi, OP here. I was using it for information such as reading, and just needed the device to be in grayscale. but only that, none of the other screens (laptop screen, 2 other monitors). Yes, I can rewrite the issue so that it doesn't mention color accuracy, if that helps. But this isn't about color calibration, it's about setting a specific monitor to grayscale and how to do it, if even possible.

Comment: @esaruoho wow you still have the issue? I'm curious to see a solution.